# kSoap, when I get my parameters on my webservice their values are null, why?

Tags: android, web-services, soap, android-ksoap2

I'm trying to make a webservice in Java (Tomcat) and I'm calling it from Android with kSoap. The parameters when my webService is called are null. I don't know why.

Data of my WebService

```
Punto Final  Información
Nombre de Servicio\:    {http://serv.trivial.com/}UsuariosWebServiceImplService
Nombre de Puerto\:  {http://serv.trivial.com/}UsuariosWebServiceImplPort
Dirección\: .../UsuariosWebService/usuarios
Clase de Implantación\: com.trivial.serv.UsuariosWebServiceImpl
```

And my code is:

```
private void registroServidor(String usuario, String regId)
{
    //http://localhost:8080/UsuariosWebService/usuarios?wsdl
    final String NAMESPACE = "http://serv.trivial.com/"; //Buscar namespace en el wsdl
    final String URL="http://10.0.2.2:8080/UsuariosWebService/usuarios";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "createUser";
    //final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://serv.trivial.com/createUser";
    final String SOAP_ACTION = "";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    request.addProperty("usuario", usuario); 
    request.addProperty("regGCM", regId);  

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = 
            new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    //envelope.doNet = true; 

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try 
    {
        transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        SoapPrimitive resultado_xml =(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        String res = resultado_xml.toString();

        if(res.equals("true"))
            Log.d("GCMTest", "Registro WS: OK.");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION!!!!!!" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("GCMTest", "Registro WS: NOK. " + e.getCause() + " || " + e.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

My WebService:

```
@Override
@WebMethod
public boolean createUser(@QueryParam("usuario") String  usuario,@QueryParam("regGCM") String regGCM) {
    System.out.println("2222");
    boolean result = false;
    UsuarioDTO dto = new UsuarioDTO();


//!!!!!! regGCM and usuario are null!!!!!!

    dto = new UsuarioDTO(regGCM, usuario);

    if (dao.findUserByUsuario(usuario) != null){    
        result = dao.update(dto);
    }else{
        result = dao.insert(dto);
    }

    System.out.println("New User info: " + dto.toString());

    return result;

}


@WebMethod
public abstract boolean createUser(@QueryParam("usuario") String  usuario,@QueryParam("regGCM") String regGCM);
```

Comment: I was trying to fix it,,, I thought that it could be because in my WSDL the names of the parameters are like arg0, arg1,,, I changed it with @WebParam(name="..."), but it still doesn't work. Could you someone give me a clue?? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I've successfully used ksoap to connect to a .NET web service, so I am not sure what your parameter names should look like when using Tomcat. I have noticed however that you do not specify the data type for your parameters - could this be the problem? Here's an example:

```
// ## init request parameters
PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
// ## usuario
pi.setName("usuario");
pi.setValue(usuario);
pi.setType(String.class);
request.addProperty(pi);
```